# Characters.FontStyle not working on cells with custom number format

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, cell

I intend to have users load a filename into an "administrative cell" (referenced in code) and have such cell "labelled" via custom number format hence omitting an additional column left adjacent to suchlike (Filename: XXX).

For readability I intend to have "Filename" in bold and "XXX" in normal .fontStyle.

It looks like .characters.FontStyle is not working on cells with custom number format (e.g. numberformat = """Filename.: ""@")

Setting the cell to standard number format applies the two .FontStyles.

Manual setting cell to bold and reversing via vba just latter does not work either. Setting custom number format after the .FontSyle "adjustment" is not working either.

```
Sub test()
    With Range("A1")
        .NumberFormat = """Filename: ""@"
        .Value = "Sample.csv"
        lngPos = InStr(.Text, ":")
        Debug.Print lngPos
        With .Characters(Start:=1, Length:=lngPos - 1).Font
            .FontStyle = "Bold"
        End With
    End With
    With Range("A2")
        .Value = "Filename: Sample.csv"
        lngPos = InStr(.Text, ":")
        Debug.Print lngPos
        With .Characters(Start:=1, Length:=lngPos - 1).Font
            .FontStyle = "Bold"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xJue.jpg")

I´d like to have the cell state "Filename: Sample.csv" with "Filename:" in bold and Sample.csv in normal font-style but only "Sample.csv" as cell.value

Comment: afaik, styles supersede default worksheet cell formatting and specific cell formatting (number format, etc) supersedes styles and conditional formatting supersedes cell formatting. if it didn't, the expressed functionality (implied override) would be useless.

Comment: good point - thanks.

The second reason for my approach is that I do not want the description in the cell value as I´ll use the cell.value in further processing.

Comment: @emte I don't think `<"Filename: "@> ` format displaying Filename in Bold letters is feasible for my attempt. I only attempted to try whether your code works and to what extent.

Comment: if you don' want a style or anything else to show in the cell then use a cell format of `;;;`. The raw cell value can be used but nothing will ever show in the cell.

Comment: I actually want the cell to show all (Filename: Sample.csv) with Filename in bold however the cell.value "just to be" Sample.csv" -  as such without description ("Filename").
I´ll have to accept that this might remain wishful thinking, though.
Thanks to all for taking the time to look into this matter!

Answer (score 0):

How about one of theses variants?

This is the representation in the worksheet:
[image: Screenshot of 3 examples]

These are the corresponding user-defined formats (yours, my first with the blocks, my 2nd and 3rd):
[image: The 2 used user-defined formats]

My first example just uses additional block characters.

My second and third example uses the same user-defined number-format with "Unicode Lisu Letters Tsa, I, La, E, Na, A, Ma, E" which are less affected from standard font formatting.
If you select a bold font (e. g. Arial Black) or light font (e. g. Apex Rounded Book) for the cell, the difference becomes visible.

Comment: Thank you Asger, the formatting is not the problem in general.
Appreciate your creative suggestions - readability is definitely improved with your suggestions. However my problems stems from not being able to have the "unique" text portion ("Filename") of the cell formatted in bold whilst having a cell.value of "Sample.csv"